# Facing Error: Uncaught RangeError - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When i Click Add to cart button then I'm encountering an `"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"` error in my application.After investigating, it appears to be related to the handleAddCart function in the Product.js file. It seems there might be an unintentional infinite recursion happening within this function.

I tried every possible solution which came in my mind and i did fixed it.

As i am learning redux-toolkit please fixed my error. Your help will be kindly appreciated

Here is my code:

```
//productSlice.js

import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchProduct = createAsyncThunk("fetchProduct", async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products");
    const data = await res.data.products;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
});

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
};

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchProduct.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.products = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchProduct.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log("Error:", action.payload);
      state.isError = true;
    });
  },
});

export const { setProduct } = productSlice.actions;

export default productSlice.reducer;

//cartSlice.js

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cart: [],
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
    },
    incrementItemInCart: (state, action) => {},
    decrementItemInCart: (state, action) => {},
  },
});

export const {
  addToCart,
  removeFromCart,
  incrementItemInCart,
  decrementItemInCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;



// store.js

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./slice/cartSlice";
import productReducer from "./slice/productSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: cartReducer,
    product: productReducer,
  },
});


//Product.js

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProduct } from "../redux/slice/productSlice";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Product = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProduct());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const getPriceAfterDiscount = (price, dis) => {
    var p = price - price * (dis / 100);
    return p.toFixed(2);
  };

  const getFirstLine = (text) => {
    if (!text) return "";
    return text.length > 50 ? text.substring(0, 50) + "..." : text;
  };

  const handleAddCart = (item) => {
    dispatch(handleAddCart(item));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="products">
        <h2>Welcome to redux toolkit store</h2>
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <div className="products-wrapper">
          {products.map((item) => (
            <div className="product-card">
              <div className="badge">Hot</div>
              <div className="product-tumb">
                <img src={item.thumbnail} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="product-details">
                <span className="product-catagory">{item.category}</span>
                <h4>
                  <Link style={{ fontSize: "14px" }} href="">
                    {item.title}
                  </Link>
                </h4>
                <p style={{ fontSize: "8px", margin: 0 }}>
                  {getFirstLine(item.description)}
                </p>
                <div className="product-bottom-details">
                  <div className="product-price">
                    <small>${item.price}</small>$
                    {getPriceAfterDiscount(item.price, item.discountPercentage)}
                  </div>
                  <div className="product-links">
                    <button onClick={() => handleAddCart(item)}>
                      Add to cart
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `handleAddCart()` in `handleAddCart()` recursive. The error is thrown because `handleAddCart()` is called infinite times. At some point the browser hits a limit.

Comment: Oh bro that works and somehow i forgot to look at that. when i did `dispatch(addToCart(item))` it works.

Answer (score 0):

you should send a value in dispatch with an action type and payload

```
dispatch({type: "addToCart", payload: {...item}});
```

like this and your reducer should be setup and you have it.
you type addToCart should take care of the rest as you are pushing it in the cart array
this is the traditional approach for redux toolkit and i beleive you ade just adding you function in dispatch which calling itself again and again obiously so

Comment: i did not tried your code but i think what i put up should be enough for your code to be up and running

Comment: Yes, i calling the handAddCart() function again and again. you justed above code it does solve the error but not adding item to cart i did like this `dispatch(addToCart(item))` and its adding item to cart.